# ​Issue with Period-End Closing

Tags: sapb1

Issue with Period-End Closing

When I try to close the end of period, I get an error message:

“To complete this document with the entered Posting Date, first define the numbering series in the Administration module.”

I have different period indicators and I use branches.

Help me please.

Thanks.

Comment: ask this type of questions better on answers.sap.com

Comment: Ok, let me ask. thank you